# Can't understand why ember tests working so strange

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I can't understand why my emberjs test code runs so strange.
I wrote a test which should only select some html elements and give me number of them. This code works:

```js
test('visiting /feedback/my', function(assert) {
  visit('/feedback/my');

  // if i remove this andThen test becomes failed
  andThen(function(){
    find(".feedback-item"); 
  });
  
  andThen(function(){
    assert.equal(find(".feedback-item").length > 0, true, "There are more than 0 feedback");
  });

  click(".feedback-item:first a");

  andThen(function() {
    assert.equal(currentURL(), '/feedback/1', "New URL is /feedback/1");
  });
});
```

But the same code but without (if i delete / comment it) this part  `andThen(function(){ find(".feedback-item")});` doesn't work. It throw's an exception: `Element .feedback-item:first a not found`.

Comment: You should checkout the [guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/testing/acceptance/#toc_wait-helpers)

Comment: Patsy Issa, i've read it many time and still don't understand why it works so strange! Visit is async operation so if i remove 1st `andThen` it shouldn't influence to behavior of the test. But it does.

Comment: [click](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14/classes/Ember.Test/methods/click?anchor=click) is also async, `andThen` waits for the promise returned to resolve before moving on with your test.

Comment: Correct. But why first `andThen` might influence to test?